# In react js how do I link my map data with different links for each image

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, react-map-gl

```
  {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Anna',
      image: one,
      price: '0.1ETH',
      href: "http://www.google.com/",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Unikorean',
      image: two,
        price: '0.2ETH',
        href: "http://www.gmail.com/",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mullaah Jutt',
      image:three,
      price: '0.3ETH',
    },
```

JSON Data. but i am not able to fetch link from here.

```
 <div className='grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-6 pt-4 py-8 '>
        {products.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className='border-2 border-transparent bg-zinc-200 rounded-lg hover:scale-105 duration-300'
          >
          <a href='item.href'>{index[0]}
             <img
              src={item.image}
              alt={item.name}
           
              className='w-full h-[180px] object-cover rounded-t-lg'
            /> </a>
            <div className='flex justify-between px-2 py-4 '>
              <p className='font-bold text-black'>{item.name}</p>
              <p>
                <span className='bg-black text-zinc-200 p-1 rounded-full'>
                  {item.price}
                </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

product displaying code where i used mapping for rendring my data but unable to fetch link kindly help.

I simply give my  tag an index id but its not working for me.
just want to have different links for every image.

Answer (score 1):

You're just passing a string here:

```
href='item.href'
```

Contrast this with *what you already do* elsewhere, which you've observed to be "working":

```
src={item.image}
```

Why change your approach to a string, instead of directly referencing the property as you do elsewhere?  Reference the object property to use its value:

```
href={item.href}
```

Comment: Can I link my pages in this as links? if yes kindly guide me.

Comment: @HaiderAli: Sorry, but it's not clear what you're asking or how it's related to the original question.